# Preservation of Edge Transitivity In Certain Class of Subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory

A graph $G$ is said to be *edge transitive* provided that, for any two edges $e$ and $f$ in $G$, there is an automorphism of $G$ sending $e$ to $f$.

Call a graph *good* if it satisfies the following conditions:

1. $G$ is connected.
2. $G$ is edge transitive.
3. For any edge $uv$, the graph $G - \{u,v\}$ is edge transitive.

(By $G - \{u, v\}$, I mean the graph $G$ with vertices $u$ and $v$ removed, as well as all edges incident to either $u$ or $v$.)

Any complete or complete bipartite graph is good, since the removal of any two vertices results in a smaller complete or complete bipartite graph, respectively, which are edge transitive.

The cycle on five vertices is also good, but larger cycles are not. I consider this to be sporadic instance and is not particularly useful for my purposes (though I would still be interested to hear about others).

I think a statement like "A graph is good if and only if it is complete, complete bipartite, or one of these finitely-many graphs" is true, hopefully with a very small "finitely-many". I would be interested in thoughts toward a proof or other examples of good graphs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Lemma**. An edge-transitive graph has at most two vertex degrees. If there are two different degrees, then the graph is bipartite. (Proof omitted).

**Theorem**. The only good graphs are (a) complete graphs, (b) complete bipartite graphs, (c) the 5-cycle.

Proof. Assume first that $G$ is acyclic, i.e. it is a tree. Then, in order for it to be edge-transitive, each edge must have a leaf node at one end. Thus, the graph is a star, which is a special case of complete bipartite.

Otherwise, consider a shortest cycle in $G$.

- If it has length 3, say $ABCA$. Since $G$ is edge-transitive and contains an odd cycle, it must be regular. After deleting, say, $AB$, the degree of $C$ has decreased by $2$.

  Now, suppose $G$ contains a node $P$ that is neighbor to neither $A$ nor $B$. Then the reduced graph must be bipartite. But then every $3$-cycle in the original graph must have included either $A$ or $B$ (or both). This contradicts the fact that by edge-transitivity $P$ must have been part of *some* 3-cycle.

  On the other hand, suppose $G$ has a node $Q$ that was neighbor to $A$ but not to $B$. Then, because again the reduced graph is bipartite, all of $Q$'s neighbors must be of the kind that was neighbor to *both* $A$ and $B$. So every neighbor of $Q$ is also a neighbor of $A$. Since $G$ is regular, this means that $Q$ and $A$ have the same neighbors, contradicting the assumption that $QB$ is not an edge.

  Thus every vertex was originally connected to both $A$ and $B$. But then, by edge-transitivity, each endpoint of *any* edge is connected to every other vertex, so $G$ is complete.
- If it has length 4, say $ABCDA$, then after deleting $AB$, both of $C$ and $D$ vertices have one less degree. In order to preserve edge transitivity then, *every* remaining vertex must have its degree decrease by $1$. Thus every vertex is neighbor of exactly one of $A$ or $B$ -- in other words $G$ is partitioned into neighbors of $A$ and neighbors of $B$,  and there cannot be any edge *inside* either of the partitions because that would constitute a 3-cycle. Thus $G$ is bipartite. Because it is edge transitive, every edge is as well connected as $AB$, so it must be *complete* bipartite.
- If it has length 5, say, $ABCDEA$, then deleting $AB$ will leave the remaining edges $CD$ and $DE$ with a node of less degree at *one* end, namely $C$ and $D$. If the result is still edge transitive, then every vertex connected to $D$ must *also* be initially connected to one of $A$ and $B$ (because its degree must have decreased). But if there is such a node except for $C$ and $E$, there would have been a 4-cycle to begin with, contradicting the minimality of 5. Thus the graph was originally $2$-regular, that is, it was the 5-cycle.
- If it has length 6 or more, then deleting an edge and its endpoints will leave the graph with too many different node degrees ... *except* if the graph was initially regular, but then after deletion there will be edges that touch a node with reduced degree and edges that don't, so the result isn't edge transitive. Therefore length $\ge 6$ is impossible.

**Corollary**. Removing two neighbor nodes from a good graph produces either a good graph or a graph with no edges at all.